# WCF service in a Webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

I need to give access to a Webservice. The problem is, ist should be on another port or better said it should be another endpoint.
Everything is fine if I create a standalone Wcf library, but how can I implement a service in my Web application?
I implemented it in code behind and it worked, but it is not accesable if I try to implement it in the web.config..
Can anybody post a web.config where a (REST) web service will start?

```
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9090/");
    private ServiceHost host;
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        host = new ServiceHost(typeof (Service1), baseAddress);

        // Code that runs on application startup
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
        // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
        // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
        // by the service.
        host.Open();


    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown
        host.Close();
    }
```

And the service

```
 namespace WebApplication.Services
    {
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        public string GetData(String value)
        {
            return "This is a Test    " + value;

        }

        public Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<CompositeType> GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(CompositeType composite)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

namespace WebApplication.Services {
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetData/{value}")]
        string GetData(String value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    } 
}
```

Edit:
Here is the web.config with the purposed changes, but this is not working, no access over the browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Ica.WebApplication-20150311133019;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Ica.WebApplication-20150311133019.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
    <controls>
      <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    </controls></pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
    </authentication>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://localhost:9090/"/>
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="Service1.svc" service="WebApplication.Services.Service1"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You really don't want to do this. Just create a new IIS application and let that host an .svc file instead of opening a ServiceHost from an ASP.NET application.

Comment: I need data from the running web application...

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you want to host your wcf library by only specifing it in your web config file.  I did that and if i'm not wrong now that should look like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="@P1" />
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  <serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="@P2" service="@P3"/>
  </serviceActivations>
 </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So you should add 'system.serviceModel' tag to your webconfig where :

@P1 is the address of your site which is hosting the service(note that this is only necessary if on that iis are hosted more than one website, so this should make it clear for the service where it belongs)

@P2 is the name of the svc file so is should be something like 'Service1.svc'

@P3 is the namespace + service name so something like 'Namespace.Service1'

Please tell me if something is not clear enough. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer! But I have no svc file. I have a Service1.cs and an interface IService1.cs

Comment: That's the whole ideea, with this you don't need the svc file, he will create it somehow behind. Just give it a try with Service.svc, and then try to access it over http://localhost:9090/Service.svc

Comment: I have something implemented exactly as you describe it but i don't remember now all the details, but that part in the web.config and the not required .svc file i'm sure of them. So if you don't solve it in few hours i'll get home and i will help you more.

Comment: :-) thank you, I will try, but withuout a relative address to the svc file this doesn't run..

Comment: It doesn't need to exist, he will associate your service with the relative address you specify in web config.

Comment: Yes it starts without errors, sorry for the misunderstanding, but doesn't work.. I mean where do I put the binding configuration for webHttp and all the stuff that is neccecary for REST over browser...

Comment: So now you can't access it over localhost:9090/Service.svc in browser?

Comment: Try like this (don't know why i can't format it proper), you should just copy paste: 

`<system.serviceModel>

 <serviceHostingEnvironment>

  <serviceActivations>

    <add relativeAddress="Service.svc" service="WebApplication.Services.Service1"/>

  </serviceActivations>

 </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />

        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

</system.serviceModel>`

Comment: Thanks, i will try it tomorrow morning!

Comment: Sorry, no way to access the server over the browser adress "http://localhost:9090/"

Comment: So you've added what i write earlier in the webconfig and deployed it on your IIS on port 9090? and you still can't access it?

Comment: No, I am running it with VS 2012 and IIS Express. This works with the code in the global file, but when I put your code in my web.config (I have updated my post above) than there is no access from the browser...